# Ionic DevApp not found in play store

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to install ionic DevApp in my android lollipop version. But I am not finding the app in play store.

Comment: Ionic DevApp is Remove From PlayStore, its Available Only App Store for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: @MDKhali is there app for android?

Comment: Another App is Expo , follow the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en

Comment: Expo is for react native  not ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Ionic is now focusing on **native-tooling** and has now moved to [**Capacitor**](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic), therefore **Ionic DevApp** is no longer maintained thus it's removed from the app stores, not completely for iOS if you've installed it before

To go around this, search it's **APK** file from google.

Or for iOS go to App Store > Your Profile Avatar > Purchased, look for Ionic DevApp then re-install it **(it will be there only if you installed it before)**.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it was removed from the Google playstore, meanwhile you can use the latest version that was available in the store:

https://apkpure.com/ionic-devapp/io.ionic.devapp